# Whitespace between header and main content

Tags: html, css

I'm building homepage for a website for my first web dev module at uni and i'm running into an issue. Below my navigation bar and above the main content section there is a whitespace for some reason. I'm using CSS grid so maybe it's due to a mistake there somewhere but not sure.

Basically I only want 1 column and 3 rows in the grid: Header - where my nav bar will go, a main-content section where a few headlines will go and a footer. But I seem to have a 4th section in between. Initially I had this whitespace below my footer and then I changed the positioning settings to 'stick' the footer to the bottom (not really knowing what I was doing) and now I think the whitespace has been pushed up or something. I want the 'main-content' section to start at the bottom border of the header and end at the top border of the footer and add a background image to it. Thanks in advance for the assistance!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint"
        content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@500&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anonymous+Pro:wght@700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="CSS/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">
    <title>Uwais Kushi-Mohammed</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="header">
            <header>
                <h1>U <span
                        style="color: white;">K
                    </span></h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav-links">
                        <li><a href="">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Experience
                                & Education</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a
                                href="">Interests</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="greeting">
                <h1>Hello,</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="intro">
                <h2>My name is <span
                        style="color: #2ac984;">Uwais
                        Kushi-Mohammed</span></span>,
                    <br />a computer science
                    student based in Sheffield,
                    England.</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="tagline">
                <h1>This Is <span
                        style="color: #2ac984;">What
                        I Do. </span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">

            <div class="footer-content">
                <div class="footer-section-about">
                    <h1 class="logo">U<span
                            style="color: white;">K
                        </span></h1>
                    <p>Welcome to my resume site.
                        My name is Uwais
                        Kushi-Mohammed, I am a
                        first year computer
                        science student at
                        Sheffield Hallam
                        University. If you want to
                        hire me for a project get
                        in touch.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-section-links">
                    <h1>Quick <span
                            style="color: white;">Links
                        </span></h1>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a
                                    href="">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a
                                    href="">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">Experience
                                    &
                                    Education</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a
                                    href="">Interests</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                </div>
                <div
                    class="footer-section-contact">
                    <h1>Contact<span
                            style="color: white;">
                            Me</span></h1>
                    <br />

                    <form class="contact-form"
                        action="results.html"
                        method="GET">
                        <div>

                            <input
                                class="contact-input"
                                type="text"
                                id="first-name"
                                placeholder="First Name...">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                class="contact-input"
                                type="text"
                                id="last-name"
                                placeholder="Last Name...">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                class="contact-input"
                                type="email"
                                id="email"
                                placeholder="Email Address...">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea
                                class="message-input"
                                id="message"
                                placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            class="button">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    Copyright 2020 &copy; |
                    Designed by Uwais
                    Kushi-Mohammed. All Rights
                    Reserved.
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "main-content"
    "footer";
}
header {
    background-color: black;
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center ;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

header h1 {
    color: #2ac984;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
   
}

.nav-links li , .nav-links li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #e4e6e3;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}
header h1:hover {
    color: #2ac984;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-links a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    color: #2ac984;
}

.main-content{
    grid-area: main-content;
    background-color: black;
}

.greeting h1{
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:  #e4e6e3;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15%;
}

.intro h2{
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #787672;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15%;
    
}

.tagline h1 {
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #e4e6e3;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 50%
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #1c1b1b;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.footer .footer-content{
    height: 300px ;
    display: flex;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about, .footer-section-links, .footer-section-contact{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 25px;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about .logo {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    color: #2ac984;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;


}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about p {
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #787672;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: justify;

}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-links h1 {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    color:#2ac984;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-links li, .footer-section-links a{
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    color:#dbdbdb;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:3px 0 10px 0; 
    padding-top: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.footer-section-links a:hover {
color: #2ac984;
margin-left: 15px;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.footer-section-contact h1 {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    color: #2ac984;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer-section-contact .contact-form .contact-input {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #c7c3c3;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 3px ;
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 0.7rem;
}
.footer-section-contact .contact-form .message-input{
    border: 0;
    background-color: #c7c3c3;
    width: 240px;
    margin:3px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 0.7rem;
    padding: 2px;
}

.button{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    line-height: 0.7rem;
    background-color:#c7c3c3;
}
::placeholder{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.footer .footer-bottom {
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    color:#787672 ;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #343a40;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

---

Combined as a snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main-content" "footer";
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

header h1 {
  color: #2ac984;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li,
.nav-links li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #e4e6e3;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
}

header h1:hover {
  color: #2ac984;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-links a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  color: #2ac984;
}

.main-content {
  grid-area: main-content;
  background-color: black;
}

.greeting h1 {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #e4e6e3;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

.intro h2 {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #787672;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

.tagline h1 {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e4e6e3;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 50%
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #1c1b1b;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer .footer-content {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about,
.footer-section-links,
.footer-section-contact {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 25px;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about .logo {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  color: #2ac984;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-about p {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #787672;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-links h1 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  color: #2ac984;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section-links li,
.footer-section-links a {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3px 0 10px 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.footer-section-links a:hover {
  color: #2ac984;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.footer-section-contact h1 {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  color: #2ac984;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer-section-contact .contact-form .contact-input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #c7c3c3;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 0.7rem;
}

.footer-section-contact .contact-form .message-input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #c7c3c3;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 0.7rem;
  padding: 2px;
}

.button {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  line-height: 0.7rem;
  background-color: #c7c3c3;
}

 ::placeholder {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.footer .footer-bottom {
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  color: #787672;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #343a40;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anonymous+Pro:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="CSS/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Uwais Kushi-Mohammed</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header">
      <header>
        <h1>U <span style="color: white;">K
                        </span></h1>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Experience
                                    & Education</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Interests</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="greeting">
        <h1>Hello,</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="intro">
        <h2>My name is <span style="color: #2ac984;">Uwais
                            Kushi-Mohammed</span></span>,
          <br />a computer science student based in Sheffield, England.
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="tagline">
        <h1>This Is <span style="color: #2ac984;">What
                            I Do. </span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">

      <div class="footer-content">
        <div class="footer-section-about">
          <h1 class="logo">U<span style="color: white;">K
                            </span></h1>
          <p>Welcome to my resume site. My name is Uwais Kushi-Mohammed, I am a first year computer science student at Sheffield Hallam University. If you want to hire me for a project get in touch.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-section-links">
          <h1>Quick <span style="color: white;">Links
                            </span></h1>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Experience
                                        &
                                        Education</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Interests</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

        </div>
        <div class="footer-section-contact">
          <h1>Contact<span style="color: white;">
                                Me</span></h1>
          <br />

          <form class="contact-form" action="results.html" method="GET">
            <div>

              <input class="contact-input" type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name...">
            </div>
            <div>
              <input class="contact-input" type="text" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name...">
            </div>
            <div>
              <input class="contact-input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address...">
            </div>
            <div>
              <textarea class="message-input" id="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="button">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
          Copyright 2020 &copy; | Designed by Uwais Kushi-Mohammed. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you only want 1 column there's little point in using `grid` layout (unless this is an assignment and you're required to use it). If you're working in only one dimension `flow` layout is more appropriate and, even simpler, if you are just flowing down the page you don't need either; the "natural" flow of `display:block` will probably get what you want.

Comment: A good way to see if you actually have an "extra" element is to inspect your html. Right click on your webpage and inspect. You'll see all your page structure and you can also select each element and check the css styling, Remeber to check for padding or margins in these elements which are being pushed away from each other.

You can also play around with the css this way and make a few adjustments.

Comment: `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` --> `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;`

Comment: As Temani Afif and Isaiah Flagg have pointed out (in different ways) you have _**told**_ the grid to use the same size for each row, by your use of `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the grid template is causing this issue.
commenting out line 13 or just deleting that line all together should fix it

Your .grid css should look like this when you're done:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; */
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "main-content"
    "footer";
```

}

or you can just delete the grid template rows line all together. Let me know if this helps! Good luck!

Comment:   that gives exactly the same display as if I get rid of the grid altogether and use plain divs without a layout container.

Comment: Well maybe i am misunderstanding your question in that case. What are you trying to accomplish differently?

Comment: hi Isaiah, I am not the asker. I was commenting that this ends up doing the same as my original comment on the question -- not using a layout.

Comment: I fixed it when i played around with the grid-template-rows. 2fr 1fr 1fr sorted it out, dont know know whats going on but hey!